# I'm trying to find a book I read about a boy and his brother discovering an alien girl who crash landed on their farm

Tags: story-identification

It is sort of sci-fi, maybe for teens, younger readers, or young adults.
The main character is a boy, he might have an older brother. There are crop circles appearing and a spaceship, maybe a shuttle, crashed on a farm and he, or his brother, or both of them together, rescued the alien girl who had beautiful owl-like eyes. I think both of them fell in love with the girl. But there was a separation in the end, I guess.
I think maybe the alien girl fell in love with his brother instead?

Comment: When did you read this book? Do you recall where it was set? Any character names you might remember?